# How can I prevent/override key translation behavior such as: µ (translated from A-m) runs the command self-insert-command

Tags: key-bindings, keymap, key-translation-map

I've bound a command to <kbd>A-m</kbd>, however some package that I load seems to modify [input translation maps](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Translation-Keymaps.html#Translation-Keymaps) (`input-decode-map`, `local-function-key-map`, `function-key-map`, `key-translation-map`) that interfere with my intended behavior for the key, which is to run the command I've bound it to. Instead when I press <kbd>A-m</kbd> I get:

`µ (translated from A-m) runs the command self-insert-command`

My questions here are:

1. How can I override this behavior if a package interferes like this?
2. How can I *quickly* zero-in on which package has interfered in this way without the slow and painful comment-packages/restart emacs cycle?
3. Prevent packages from overriding my custom settings-- or at least warn me when modifying the input maps so I can easily figure out which package without hunting?

Comment: I guess it is the builtin `iso-transl` package, that has defined the translation

Comment: As for disabling it could you try (I tried to infer this from the source of the package so not sure it will work, especially since I do not know how to press 'A-m')

`(let ((vec (vconcat "m")))
  (aset vec 0 (logior (aref vec 0) ?\A-\^@))
  (define-key key-translation-map vec nil))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This behavior seems to introduced by the packages `iso-transl`. From the library's commentary (<kbd>M-x</kbd>`find-library`<kbd>RET</kbd>`iso-transl`<kbd>RET</kbd>)

> Loading this package defines three ways of entering the non-ASCII
>   printable characters with codes above 127: the prefix C-x 8, or the
>   Alt key, or a dead accent key.  For example, you can enter uppercase
>   A-umlaut as `C-x 8 " A' or`Alt-" A' (if you have an Alt key) or
>   `umlaut A' (if you have an umlaut/diaeresis key).

To disable the keybinding for <kbd>A-m</kbd> introduced by this package add something like this to your init file

```
(with-eval-after-load 'iso-transl
  (let ((vec (vconcat "m")))
    (aset vec 0 (logior (aref vec 0) ?\A-\^@))
    (define-key key-translation-map vec nil)))
```

Alternatively if you want to disable all key translation set `iso-transl-char-map` to nil before `iso-transl` has loaded. Other way would be map over `iso-transl-char-map` and unset keys like above, something like this

```
(dolist (transl-char iso-transl-char-map)
  (let ((vec (vconcat (car transl-char))))
    (aset vec 0 (logior (aref vec 0) ?\A-\^@))
    (define-key key-translation-map vec nil)))
```

After which your binding for the key will start working. This works, I tested by instructing emacs to use `meta` key as `alt` modifier and `alt` key as `meta` modifier by doing

```
(setq x-meta-keysym 'alt)
(setq x-alt-keysym 'meta)
```

Now <kbd>M-m</kbd> will act as <kbd>A-m</kbd>, to disable it do the reverse of the above.

I feel you should [report](http://debbugs.gnu.org/) this as a bug to emacs-devel, there should be a way to easily disable to the key translations introduced by `iso-transl` (perhaps there is a way, but I don't see it).

Comment: See my question https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/61415/9874 Basically the function describe-bindings is the one that calls iso-transl in. As a fix Aquamacs patched iso-transl to allow it to be unloaded.