# How can I stop iso-transl running

Tags: key-bindings, debugging

I have run the macport emacs 27 on macOS.

The bindings of my keys as as per mac-keys-mode (and aquamacs) and have Command key acting as alt.

Thus all my key bindings are A-key

This normally works.

However (iso-transl-ctl-x-8-map) copies the ctl-x-8-map into alt key bindings thus wiping out my bindings.

How do I stop iso-transl being run.

On the latest time this happend the debug stack shows

```
Debugger entered--entering a function:
* iso-transl-define-keys((("* " . [160]) (" " . [160]) ("*!" . [161]) ("!" . [161]) ("\"\"" . [168]) ("\"A" . [196]) ("\"E" . [203]) ("\"I" . [207]) ("\"O" . [214]) ("\"U" . [220]) ("\"a" . [228]) ("\"e" . [235]) ("\"i" . [239]) ("\"o" . [246]) ("\"s" . [223]) ("\"u" . [252]) ("\"y" . [255]) ("''" . [180]) ("'A" . [193]) ("'E" . [201]) ("'I" . [205]) ("'O" . [211]) ("'U" . [218]) ("'Y" . [221]) ("'a" . [225]) ("'e" . [233]) ("'i" . [237]) ("'o" . [243]) ("'u" . [250]) ("'y" . [253]) ("*$" . [164]) ("$" . [164]) ("*+" . [177]) ("+" . [177]) (",," . [184]) (",C" . [199]) (",c" . [231]) ("*-" . [173]) ("-" . [173]) ("*." . [183]) ("." . [183]) ("//" . [247]) ("/A" . [197]) ("/E" . [198]) ("/O" . [216]) ("/a" . [229]) ("/e" . [230]) ("/o" . [248]) ("1/2" . [189]) ("1/4" . [188]) ...))
  byte-code("\301\10!\210\302\303!\207" [iso-transl-char-map iso-transl-define-keys provide iso-transl] 2)
  map-keymap(#f(compiled-function (key item) #<bytecode 0x1fe107d7ed09>) iso-transl-ctl-x-8-map)
  keymap-canonicalize(iso-transl-ctl-x-8-map)
  describe-buffer-bindings(#<buffer file-management.org> [24])
  which-key--get-current-bindings([24])
  which-key--get-bindings([24] nil nil)
  which-key--create-buffer-and-show([24])
  which-key--update()
```

SO in this case which-key called describe-buffer-bindings but it could be something else. I do not need or want these extra key bindings

Comment: Can't you just have Command act as Meta?

Comment: No as the mac key mappings i have from mac-keys mode use cmd as alt + alt is what is written on the key (I use a PC keyboard) plus the init also runs under Aquamacs that uses A-x key bindings. Basically manageable except iso-transl does this at low level and can't be controlled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using Aquamacs as my main emacs which uses Alt as the Apple command key (A PC keyboard has Alt written on that key).

Aquamacs had found this or a similar problem and so had patched iso-transl.el to alther its behaviour - it made it a mode so could set or unset the Alt key bindings.

A comment in Aquamacs source code gives more information

> Note that C-h b will autoload this package, which is one reason why the more destructive key sequences (without C-x 8 prefix) are only defined in `iso-transl-mode', and are thus reversible.

So for more normal emacs Alt key bindings include these keys (which I think is wrong as they are an arbitrary list especially as you can change the keyboard mapping in the OS to other languages on the fly).

For simplicity bind the Apple command key to hyper or super and don't bind anything to Alt.