# How to remap A-m? It is currently bound to μ

Tags: key-bindings

For some reason, pressing `A-m` (i.e. typing `m` while holding the `Alt` [modifier key](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Modifier-Keys.html)) inserts the `μ` character. I want to remove this binding so that I can then bind this key sequence to some interactive command. Unfortunately, `(global-unset-key (kbd "A-m"))` does not accomplish this, and neither does `(global-set-key (kbd "A-m") nil)`.

With `emacs-mac`, I was still able to bind that key sequence to a command by doing something like `(global-set-key (kbd "μ") 'mu4e)`, but this doesn't work with `emacs-plus`.

(To avoid confusion, I am referring to the `Alt` rather than the `Meta` modifier. The latter is often bound to the `Alt` key and sometimes incorrectly referred to as "Alt".)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I prevent/override key translation behavior such as: µ (translated from A-m) runs the command self-insert-command](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/17508/how-can-i-prevent-override-key-translation-behavior-such-as-%c2%b5-translated-from)

Comment: It's really too bad that people are quick to pose - and answer - questions, without checking whether such a question already exists. It would be more helpful to check - and even more helpful to edit the original question if it can be improved. Not to single anyone out - lots of people do it; it's easier and quicker, but it makes the Q&A less useful for others.

Comment: Big deal: (1) it interferes with (complicates) searching, whether googling or SE searching, (2) it isn't fair to the original OP and those who answered that (see #1), (3) it leads to duplicate answers too, (4) it makes for more of a maintenance burden, for those who try to improve things here. In a nutshell, it violates Occam's Razor: Don't multiply things unnecessarily. It's easy to be lazy about looking for an existing Q, but due diligence is part of helping others here, just like editing, voting, closing, etc. All of this should be obvious - a Q isn't only for the OP; it's for the world.

Comment: It may (or may not) help the world find *your* version of the question. It doesn't help the world in the sense of pointing to a *unique instance*of the question and all its answers, in one place. Duplicate answers and duplicate questions present the same difficulty - for everyone. They add nothing but noise. Again: **Occam**. Why do it? Or turn it around: Why not 100 duplicates of the same question? And in any case, that's the intent of the site (all SE sites) - duplicates are not a good thing. Gardens sometimes need weeding - or they need mulch to prevent ease of weeds to sprout everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This binding is defined in `key-translation-map`.  You can remove it like so:

```
(define-key key-translation-map (kbd "A-m") nil)
```

For more details, <kbd>M-x</kbd> `find-library` <kbd>RET</kbd> `iso-transl` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Comment: Duplicate question.